# Formula Field creation

Tags: custom-object, formula, formula-field

I have created the Custom Field Field called `DateTime1__c` with type as (Date and Time) in order object.

When creating record in object, if i give value for `DateTime1__c` field, then another custom formula field called `DateTime2__c` is need to populate with the value after six months of `DateTime1__c`.

What formula i have to give while creating `DateTime2__c` to display the value after six months of `DateTime1__c`?

Answer (score 4):

```
DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(if((MONTH(DATEVALUE( DateTime1__c )) + 6)
<13,YEAR(DATEVALUE(DateTime1__c)),
YEAR((DATEVALUE(DateTime1__c))+1)))+"-"+
TEXT(if(MONTH(DATEVALUE(DateTime1__c))+6 <13,MONTH(DATEVALUE(
DateTime1__c ) ) + 6,MONTH(DATEVALUE(DateTime1__c )) - 6
))+"-"+TEXT(DAY( (DATEVALUE(DateTime1__c)))) +" "+TEXT(VALUE( MID(
TEXT( DateTime1__c  ), 12, 2 ) ))+":"+TEXT(VALUE( MID( TEXT(
DateTime1__c  ), 15, 2 ) ))+":"+TEXT(VALUE( MID( TEXT(
DateTime1__c  ), 18, 2 )) ))
```

Comment: while i am trying to get requirement using the above formula I am facing following error : Incorrect parameter type for function 'MONTH()'. Expected Date, received DateTime

Comment: @cloudcomputinginsalesforce edit has been made it will work fine now

Comment: : Formula result is data type (Date), incompatible with expected data type (Date/Time). @Manjot Singh,I want output in Date and Time format

Comment: @cloudcomputinginsalesforce i have changed type now

Comment: where is my Custom field - DateTime1__c  in formula to add  the value six months after

Comment: @cloudcomputinginsalesforce i have added field now.

Comment: @cloudcomputinginsalesforce can you tell me your timeZone?

Comment: Indian standard time @Manjot singh

Comment: Then above formula will work

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this formula

```
    if( MONTH(DATEVALUE( test_dt__c))> 6,  DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(YEAR(DATEVALUE( test_dt__c))+1)+"-" +TEXT((MONTH(DATEVALUE( test_dt__c))+6)-12+ ( if(DAY( DATEVALUE( test_dt__c)) == 31 && MONTH(DATEVALUE( test_dt__c)) != 1&& MONTH(DATEVALUE( test_dt__c)) != 7, 1,0)  ))+"-" +TEXT(if(DAY( DATEVALUE( test_dt__c)) == 31 && (MONTH(DATEVALUE( test_dt__c)) == 1 ||  MONTH(DATEVALUE( test_dt__c)) = 7), DAY( DATEVALUE( test_dt__c)),1) )+" "+TEXT(VALUE( MID( TEXT( test_dt__c- 5 ), 12, 2 ) ))+":"+ MID( TEXT( test_dt__c- 5 ), 15, 2 )+":"+ MID( TEXT( test_dt__c- 5 ), 18, 2 ) ), 

DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT(YEAR(DATEVALUE( test_dt__c)) + if(DAY( DATEVALUE( test_dt__c)) == 31 && MONTH(DATEVALUE( test_dt__c)) != 1 && MONTH(DATEVALUE( test_dt__c)) != 7 && MONTH(DATEVALUE( test_dt__c)) == 6, 1,0)   )+"-" +TEXT(MONTH(DATEVALUE( test_dt__c))+ 6  +if(DAY( DATEVALUE( test_dt__c )) == 31 && MONTH(DATEVALUE( test_dt__c)) != 1 && MONTH(DATEVALUE( test_dt__c)) != 7, 1,0))   +"-" +      TEXT(if(DAY( DATEVALUE( test_dt__c )) == 31 && (MONTH(DATEVALUE( test_dt__c)) == 1 ||  MONTH(DATEVALUE( test_dt__c)) = 7), DAY( DATEVALUE( test_dt__c)),1) )   +" "+TEXT(VALUE( MID( TEXT( test_dt__c - 5 ), 12, 2 ) ))+":"+ MID( TEXT( test_dt__c- 5 ), 15, 2 )+":"+ MID( TEXT( test_dt__c- 5 ), 18, 2 ) ))
```

Where `date/time` is your field and `TZoffset` is the difference between the user’s time zone and GMT.

This is the working example I checked in my org.

[Refernce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.usefulFormulaFields.meta/usefulFormulaFields/formula_examples_dates.htm)

Comment: while saving this formula field it is showing error like :Field TZoffset does not exist. Check spelling. How I can use this TZoffset  @Tushar sharma

Comment: @cloudcomputinginsalesforce TZoffset is the time difference read reference document for more information.

Comment: yes I am reading your reference, while i am reading this reference,I unable to get what exactly TZoffset is? Please provide an example how to use it

Comment: @cloudcomputinginsalesforce for testing take any integer like 1,2 or 3. in real world if your Timezone is GMT+5 so 5 is the number you need.

Comment: @cloudcomputinginsalesforce check my updated answer you might need to adjust `TZoffset`

Comment: it is result in 1 1/2 year duration,I want only six month duration,can you explain the formula

Comment: I want your Formula description , what you have done @Tushar sharma

Comment: if it is after june date is coming for 6 monthsif it is below or os equal june, date is coming after 18 months in results

Comment: @cloudcomputinginsalesforce there is one typo in else part. Check now.

Comment: There is a small problem with above formula @Tushar Sharma.... Its working good except in one single case. The issue is, If we select 31st march, Then the result should like 31st march+ 6 months, which means 31st september. But we do not have this date(31st sep). So, then the result should be 1st  October. But in this its giving Error as in result. This is giving error in all 31st dates except January 31st. (Beacuse 31st January + 6 months is equal to July 31st ).

Answer (score 2):

You can write apex trigger on your object and in triggers u may use something like

```
DateTime d = DateTime.now();
DateTime d1 = d.addMonths(6);
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: I dont want apex class or apex trigger, I want Formula field only @Ashwani Kumar Thank you for your Guidance,I will put Vote for your answer for suggesting

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to achieve this using customization not by apex code - 
You can do by using workflow rule. 
The example is based on following requirement but you can modify for your use case -

```
The customer has a start date (in the example below, it is called "Effective date") and has a number field called Policy term which is a piclikst that gives the number of month an opportunity runs for (in the example below, the values were 1 Month, 6 Months and 12 Months).

He wants to add the policy term to the start date in order to calculate the "Renewal date".

This solution will even work on leap years !
```

The solution is listed on salesforce help articles - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000002391&language=en_US&type=1